# Intercepting jQuery ajax

Tags: ajax, security, jquery

If I am going to encrypt the data being passed by jQuery ajax prior to sending to the network (regardless if the network is SSL'd or not), where can I inject that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept all ajax queries initiated by jQuery, examine their content and change them *(encrypt in your case)* by using ajax prefilter in jQuery. With is approach you can modify all requests' contents at one place globally.

Details: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Answer (score 0):

Well, `jQuery.ajax` has a `data` field, which corresponds to the data sent in your request. So cleanest would be to set this field as a call to your encoding function.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: yourDataEncodingFunction(),
    ...
});
```

Remember `data` must be Key/Value pairs, so be sure that's what your function returns.